# Prevent collisions in an animated game

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision

I have been trying to program a way of preventing my character from touching a wall so he couldn't go trough it but I can't find a proper way of doing like you can see in this video (that I recorded). Sorry about the (decent) mic quality : https://youtu.be/jhTSDgSXXa8. Also I said prevent the collision but rather it detects it and stops but you can go through.

The collision code is :

```
foreach (PictureBox pbMur in pbListeMurs)
{
    if (pbCharacterCat.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbMur.Bounds))
    {
        if (pbCharacterCat.Right > pbMur.Left)
        {
            bWalkRight = false;
            bIdle = true;              
        }                        
     } 
}
```

Thank you ! :D

Comment: And your current code is...?

Comment: So you want us to go somewhere else, watch a video of a game and then imagine what the code might look like and devise collision code?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @InBetween Yo sorry I forgot ! It has been added !

Comment: You are checking if the cat is inside a wall, but you don't correct the situation, you must pull the cat outside the wall :D

Comment: @Gusman And how do I do that without ruining the animation. Because teleporting the cat back would be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are using `bIdle` and `walkRight`, but these types of boolean flags are easy to get wrong and it turns your whole code into a complete mess as you typically try to plug holes and end up springing new ones in the process.

First of all, why do you even need them? Wouldn't this be enough?

```
var newPotentialCharacterBounds = 
    GetNewBounds(pbCharacterCat.Bounds, movementDirection);
var collidedWalls = pbListeMurs.Where(wall => 
    wall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(newPotentialCharacterBounds));

if (!collidedWall.Any())
{
    pbCharacterCat.Bounds = newPotentialCharacterBounds   
}

//else do nothing
```

How does this work? Well, the premise is that your character can't start in an invalid position, and if it is never allowed to reach an invalid position then you never need to undo movements or reset positions.

I'd propose you create an enumeration that describes all possible directions:

```
enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right };
```

When the corresponding direction command is given, get the potential new position of the character (`newPotentialCharacterBounds` and `GetNewBounds`). If that position collides with anything, simply do nothing, if it doesn't, move!

UPDATE: Pseudocode follows:

```
//event handler for move right fires, and calls:
TryMove(pbCharacterCat, Direction.Right)


//event handler for move left fires and calls:
TryMove(pbCharacterCat, Direction.Left)

//etc.

private static Rectangle GetNewBounds(
    Rectangle current, Direction direction)
{
     switch (direction)
     {
          case Direction.Right:
          {
              var newBounds = current;
              newBounds.Offset(horizontalDelta, 0);
              return newBounds;
          }
          case Direction.Left:
          {
              var newBounds = current;
              newBounds.Offset(-horizontalDelta, 0);
              return newBounds;
           }
          //etc.   
}

//uses System.Linq
private bool TryMove(Control ctrl, Direction direction)
{
    var newBounds = 
        GetNewBounds(ctrl.Bounds, direction);
    var collidedWalls = pbListeMurs.Where(wall => 
        wall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(newBounds));

    if (!collidedWall.Any())
    {
        ctrl.Bounds = newBounds;   
        return true;
    }

    //Can't move in that direction
    Debug.Assert(collidedWall.Single); //sanity check
    return false;
}
```

Becuase `TryMove` returns if the movement was successful or not, now you can leverage that information; different sound effects for instance, etc.

Comment: I sort of see what you are showing me but don't quite get how to use it tbh.